# JSON/ Jackson: Recursive polymorphic deserialization without type field

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am currently struggling with the deserialization of a JSON data structure that looks something like this:

**Example 1:**

```
{
    "condition": "AND",
    "rules": [
        {
            "id": "FIELD1",
            "field": "FIELD1",
            "type": "string",
            "input": "select",
            "operator": "equal",
            "value": [
                "a1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "FIELD2",
            "field": "FIELD2",
            "type": "string",
            "input": "select",
            "operator": "in",
            "value": [
                "b1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
{
    "condition": "AND",
    "rules": [
        {
            "id": "FIELD1",
            "field": "FIELD1",
            "type": "string",
            "input": "select",
            "operator": "equal",
            "value": [
                "a1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "FIELD2",
            "field": "FIELD2",
            "type": "string",
            "input": "select",
            "operator": "in",
            "value": [
                "b1",
                "b2",
                "b3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "FIELD3",
            "field": "FIELD3",
            "type": "string",
            "input": "select",
            "operator": "in",
            "value": [
                "c1",
                "c2",
                "c3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "FIELD4",
            "field": "FIELD4",
            "type": "string",
            "input": "select",
            "operator": "in",
            "value": [
                "d1",
                "d2",
                "d3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "condition": "AND",
            "rules": [
                {
                    "id": "FIELD5",
                    "field": "FIELD5",
                    "type": "string",
                    "input": "select",
                    "operator": "equal",
                    "value": [
                        "e1"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "FIELD6",
                    "field": "FIELD6",
                    "type": "string",
                    "input": "select",
                    "operator": "in",
                    "value": [
                        "f1",
                        "f1",
                        "f3",
                        "f4",
                        "f5",
                        "f6"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "condition": "AND",
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "id": "FIELD7",
                            "field": "FIELD7",
                            "type": "string",
                            "input": "select",
                            "operator": "in",
                            "value": [
                                "g1",
                                "g2",
                                "g3"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There are many instances of such a structure that I have to process. It is the output of a rule builder. I can't change the format of the JSON, I have to work with what I got. The structure is recursive, there can be multiple levels.

I am using the ObjectMapper from Jackson and build some inner classes to map the data.

```
static class Wrapper {
        public Condition condition;

        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
        @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(RuleGroup.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(Rule.class) })
        public List<AbstractRuleObject> rules;
    }

    static abstract class AbstractRuleObject {
        public Condition condition;
        public List<Rule> rules;

        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
        @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(RuleGroup.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(Rule.class) })
        public List<AbstractRuleObject> ruleGroups;
    }

    static class RuleGroup extends AbstractRuleObject {
        public Condition condition;
        public List<Rule> rules;
    }

    static class Rule extends AbstractRuleObject {
        public String id;
        public String field;
        public String type;
        public String input;
        public Operator operator;
        public List<String> value;
    }
```

Most instances look like Example 1, and for those it already works fine, but there are more complex ones, like Example 2, actually even more complex and deeper ones than Example 2, but the structure is always the same:

There is always a "RuleGroup" with one "Condition" and one list of "Rule", the rules can either be a "Rule" or again a "RuleGroup", there is no limit how deep you can go, but I believe it's not deeper than 4 or 5 levels. There can be multiple "RuleGroups" per level

I can't parse these deeper examples, with the current code and Example 2 I get the following error:

> Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class
> MyClass$AbstractRuleObject]: Cannot deduce unique subtype of
> `MyClass$AbstractRuleObject` (2 candidates match)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule and RuleGroup have nothing in common, except that they can both appear in a list, so `AbstractRuleObject` should not have `condition` and `rules` on it -- a `Rule`  doesn't have those properties.

We can get rid of `Wrapper` too, as it's identical to `RuleGroup`.

This works for me:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class ParseExample {
    static class RuleObject {
    }

    static class RuleGroup extends RuleObject {

        public String condition;
        @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
        @JsonSubTypes({
                @JsonSubTypes.Type(RuleGroup.class),
                @JsonSubTypes.Type(Rule.class)})
        public List<RuleObject> rules;
    }

    static class Rule extends RuleObject{

        public String id;
        public String field;
        public String type;
        public String input;
        public String operator;
        public List<String> value;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonParser parser = mapper.createParser(ParseExample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test2.json"));
        RuleGroup w = parser.readValueAs(new TypeReference<RuleGroup>() {});
    }
}
```

Jackson version:

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>2.12.4</version>
      </dependency>
```

Result:

```
args = {String[0]@1361} []
mapper = {ObjectMapper@1362} 
parser = {UTF8StreamJsonParser@1363} 
w = {ParseExample$RuleGroup@1364} 
 condition = "AND"
 rules = {ArrayList@1366}  size = 5
  0 = {ParseExample$Rule@1368} 
  1 = {ParseExample$Rule@1369} 
  2 = {ParseExample$Rule@1370} 
  3 = {ParseExample$Rule@1371} 
  4 = {ParseExample$RuleGroup@1372} 
   condition = "AND"
   rules = {ArrayList@1380}  size = 3
    0 = {ParseExample$Rule@1382} 
    1 = {ParseExample$Rule@1383} 
    2 = {ParseExample$RuleGroup@1384} 
     condition = "AND"
     rules = {ArrayList@1386}  size = 1
      0 = {ParseExample$Rule@1388}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Everyone is pointing to the class-level usage of these annotations, but in my case they actually belonged on the property.